# Can Z3 handle sinusoidal and exponential functions

Tags: z3

Based on some non-linear constraints on `$a_k$,$b_k$`, I have to find feasible set of the following fourier series expression:

```
$ x(t)= {a_0+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}   (a_k\cos(2\pi f_0 kt)+(b_k\sin(2\pi f_0 kt))}
```

Whereas constraints on `$a_k$,$b_k$` and `$a_0$` are

```
$ L \leq a_0 \leq U $

$ Lower_bound \leq a_k^2+b_k^2 \leq Upper_bound
```

Can I do this using Z3?

In addition to this can I use Z3 for exponential functions having complex powers, e.g. in fourier transform expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Z3 does not have support for transcendental functions such as `sin`, `cos` and exponential yet. The current version can only handle nonlinear polynomial constraints. 
You may consider the [MetiTarski theorem prover](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Arith/). BTW, MetiTarski uses Z3 to discharge nonlinear polynomial constraints.